# Windows Phone 7: Is it possible to make changes in WP app page after submission/update?

Tags: windows-phone-7, updates, submission

Firstly, sorry for this "non-code question". But I've been searching for hours without any solutions... My scenario is as follow:

1. I've submited a WP7 app and all of its descriptions and images on Windows Store. The app has passed certification;
2. I've uploaded a new .xap file (to update the previous one). The proccess is still under certification analysis;
3. I've discovered a bug in my last .xap file update. Also I'd like to change some of my app descriptions/images;
4. MY ISSUE POINT: there's no option to do any operation, such as changing descriptions and/or canceling the update proccess.

**So my question is: Is it possible to make changes in WP app page after submission/update?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no option to revoke the submitted app, until it is either approved or rejected by Microsoft store.

That is why it is always better to keep the app publishing in the 'Manual publishing' mode.

You will have to wait for approval or rejection from MS store, and then resubmit the app.

Otherwise, contact the support team. They may help you.

Comment: I've read about this lack of feature before, but I was wondering that I was just missing the solution or something else.
Anyway... Man, this is really annoying... :(

Comment: Yep .. That is really annoying. I have also suffered :(

Answer (score 0):

As the app has been submitted now, you may change the publish mode to MANUAL so as to update the xap again and make the updated xap available on store